# How do I determine which paths are used for the composer cache?

Tags: php, composer-php

https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#cache-dir

Is there a way I can verify which paths it is actually using?

And secondly the documentation does not seem valid - I don't have any `~/cache` directory OR `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/composer`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are looking for your global composer configuration you can use the [`config`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#config) command:

```
composer config --global --list
```

Sample output form my docker container:

```
$ composer config --global --list | grep cache
[cache-dir] /tmp/cache
[cache-files-dir] {$cache-dir}/files (/tmp/cache/files)
[cache-repo-dir] {$cache-dir}/repo (/tmp/cache/repo)
[cache-vcs-dir] {$cache-dir}/vcs (/tmp/cache/vcs)
[cache-ttl] 15552000
[cache-files-ttl] 15552000
[cache-files-maxsize] 300MiB (314572800)
```

You might have missed the last part of the documentation, though:

> ### cache-dir
>
> Defaults to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Composer` on Windows, `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/composer` on unix systems that follow the XDG Base Directory Specifications, and `$home/cache` on other unix systems. Stores all the caches used by Composer. **See also [COMPOSER_HOME](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home).**

*Source:* https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#cache-dir, emphasis mine.

So I think, here you missred `$home/cache` to be `~/cache` when it is actually `$COMPOSER_HOME/cache`

From my docker container still, which confirm the `/tmp/cache` folder raised by the config command:

```
$ echo $XDG_CACHE_HOME

$ echo $home

$ echo $COMPOSER_HOME
/tmp
```

So, in short, if set, the `$COMPOSER_HOME` takes the precedence:

```
$ echo $COMPOSER_HOME
/tmp
$ unset COMPOSER_HOME
$ echo $COMOPSER_HOME

$ composer config -gl | grep 'cache-dir'
[cache-dir] /root/.composer/cache
[cache-files-dir] {$cache-dir}/files (/root/.composer/cache/files)
[cache-repo-dir] {$cache-dir}/repo (/root/.composer/cache/repo)
[cache-vcs-dir] {$cache-dir}/vcs (/root/.composer/cache/vcs)

$ echo $HOME
/root
$ whoami
root
```

As you can see here, after unsetting `$COMPOSER_HOME`, I end up with the home of my user (root here, which would be a bad practice for composer but I am on docker, for the demo).

So what you should read in

> By default it points to (...) /home/<user>/.composer

*Source:* https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home

Is

> By default, **when the variable is not set**, it points to (...) /home/<user>/.composer